# Date variable still contains todays date after assigning it the value of upcoming Friday

Tags: powershell

I have a little powershell script to find the date of the upcoming Friday. However after assigning the value of the Friday date, my date variable still prints out todays date.

```
$date = Get-Date

for($i=1; $i -le 7; $i++)
{        
    if($date.AddDays($i).DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday')
    {
        $date.AddDays($i)
        break
    }
}
Write-Host "$date"
```

Comment: @ArcSet: he is expecting that date to be displayed which is going inside the if block. He has to assign that to $date variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddDays` seems to return new date object and not update the date object in `$date`. Try assigning `$date` to the new date inside the if statement as follows:

```
 $date = $date.AddDays($i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = Get-Date

for($i=1; $i -le 7; $i++)
{        
    if($date.AddDays($i).DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday')
    {
        $date = $date.AddDays($i)
        break
    }
}
Write-Host "$date"
```

You have to return the value you're assigning to $date back to itself.

Answer (score 0):

You probably tested it yesterday (Wednesday) because it works today.
The problem in your code is that it reuses the same `$Date` each time and probably step over the expected date:

```
Date + 1
Date + 3 (1 + 2)
Date + 6 (1 + 2 + 3)
...
```

In other words, the `$date = Get-Date` should be in your loop.

```
(Get-Date).AddDays((1..7 | Where {(Get-Date).AddDays($_).DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday'}))
```

Comment: I have put a minimized function in my answer.